# How to switch vue.js router views without rerendering html

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue and the official router. My app has some views and one view has a form with some inputs. Now I am looking for a solution to switch between to views without loosing the input data / rerendering the view. An extra save button in the form isnt an option.

Probably my problem is close to different way how v-if and v-show works:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

I build an example based on the vue router example:
https://jsfiddle.net/okuc64d2/6/

```js
const Foo = { 
    data: function () {
            return {
                text: "abc"
            }
        },
  template: '<div>VIEW A: <input v-model="text" placeholder="edit me"></div>' 
}
const Bar = { 
    data: function () {
            return {
                text: "123"
            }
        },
  template: '<div>VIEW B: <input v-model="text" placeholder="edit me"></div>' 
}

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')

// Now the app has started!
```

```css
.router-link-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Go to  Foo</li>
    <li>Change input</li>
    <li>Go to Bar</li>
    <li>Go back to Foo</li>
    <li>Input is resetted</li>
  </ul>
  
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: use vuex to store the data? clear it once its submitted?

Comment: No I dont use vuex at the moment. Its only a small app but if thats the best way I will have a look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Keep-alive may help: `<keep-alive><router-view></router-view></keep-alive>`

Comment: Keep alive works perfect with my first test. Thanks! I hope I dont have to come back ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can save input on keyup to vuex store and use that to your component.